# Sort List of tuples by numeric values Python

Tags: python, sorting

How do I sort the below list of tuples by the second element?

```
[('8B', u'11'), ('8P', u'2.3'), ('8C', u'1.6')]
```

Expected Result would be:

```
[('8C', u'1.6'), ('8P', u'2.3'), ('8B', u'11')]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of *"did absolutely no research"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and confirmed in Python IDLE

```
my_list = [('8B', u'11'), ('8P', u'2.3'), ('8C', u'1.6')]
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
print(my_list)
```

Got

```
[('8C', '1.6'), ('8P', '2.3'), ('8B', '11')]
```

Comment: Excellent! thanks a lot! i cant upvote you because of lower points!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Going forward, please try to remember to search for similar/related questions before posting a new one.